# Why can not I compile the tensorflow-r1.99 with VS2017 using CMake?

Tags: tensorflow, cmake

Today, I got the [tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.99) from the github and then used it with CMake to compile it.

This is my vs2017 CMD Command：

```
C:\...\build2017>cmake .. -A x64 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE="C:\Anaconda3\python.exe"
-DPYTHON_LIBRARIES="C:\Anaconda3\libs\python35.lib"
-Dtensorflow_WIN_CPU_SIMD_OPTIONS=/arch:AVX
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
-Dtensorflow_BUILD_CC_EXAMPLE=ON
-Dtensorflow_ENABLE_GRPC_SUPPORT=OFF
```

Then I use

```
MSBuild /p:Configuration=Release tf_python_build_pip_package.vcxproj
```

However, I got 48 errors. Most of these errors are like this

```
“absl/strings/string_view.h”: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please, provide **complete** message for at least one error of this type. Complete message contains information about inclusion chain from the source file to the header file, which includes `absl/strings/string_view.h`.

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow release 1.10.0 was the last release supporting cmake and it is no longer supported in favor of bazel.

Refer to the TF 1.10.0 release notes:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/RELEASE.md#breaking-changes